# How to create a file on remote server using capistrano 3.1

Tags: centos, capistrano3

I am having a problem creating a file on a remote server using capistrano. When I attempting to create my file, no matter what I try I "no such file or directory". If I read the documentation correctly, I should be able to use backticks or %x to accomplish this but so far I have not been able to make this work.

The idea is, if the file doesn't exist I want to create the file. Everything seems to work up until it is time to actually create the file.

The code I am currently working with is:

```
on roles(:app) do |host|
  if capture("ls -1 #{fetch(:rails_conf_root)}").split("\n").include?("#{fetch(:application)}.conf")
    info "#{fetch(:application)}.conf already exists"
  else
    info "#{fetch(:application)}.conf does not exist"
    `sudo echo "I am attempting to create a file for #{fetch(:application}}" > /home/deploy/#{fetch(:appliation)}.txt`
  end
```

So far I have not had any luck in creating this file and I am not sure what I am missing to get this to work properly.

Comment: Decided to create the file locally and use upload! to push the file to the server. I recall there being a method called 'run' that I could have used for this but apparently that has been moved from version 3.1. Either way I guess this was the better or easier approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'execute' or 'sudo'

```
within fetch(:deploy_to) do 
  execute "echo "I am attempting to create a file for #{fetch(:application}}" > #{fetch(:appliation)}.txt"
end
```